# How to resolve requirement: Import-Package:

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, plugins, ant

The scope of this question applies after you have created an RCP app in eclipse following Vogella's tutorial linked below.  This assumes your feature, product, and father project are created.  In this state the feature is delegated the task of building, therefore all dependencies need to be resolved in the feature build.properties file.

This question addresses when the missing dependency needs to be installed, i.e. is downloaded manually because the missing dependency is not on the class path. The class path determines what plugins are available in the feature/included-plugins tab.  The plugins listed in the feature/included tab can be added as plugins for dependencies to your plugin.  This list gets appended to your feature.xml file which gets linked to your build.properties file!  See Solution below.

Eclipse nomenclature interchanges the ideas of plugins=dependencies and treats them the same.  We know this by the names of the tabs.

The intent of this question is aimed at using existing Eclipse capability to develop an RCP application that uses objects from a third party plugin to create a custom workflow.

This error is thrown because my RCP app third party plugin requires this dependency which was not included in Eclipse ICE nor the plugin itself.

The first thing I tried was to install the plugin directly from the Eclipse Marketplace.

The string org.apache.commons.beanutils returned nothing so I went to apache and downloaded the plugin manually.

I then researched how to install a plugin in Eclipse manually.

I've learned not to simply drop the plugin into the Eclipse/dropins folder, which does nothing.
I've learned that this advice is lacking probably due to age of post.
I've learned when Maven is configured correctly, all the dependencies can automatically be resolved.

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/813199/

This says plugin dependencies are resolved by looking at four files.

"The plug-in definition, the product file, the run configurations and the target definition."

The plug-in definition I'm not sure what that is other than the plugin.xml file.  The product file has been configured to launch the third party plugin.  I've learned the run-configuration has a list of plugins and the third party plugin is not listed there.

I've learned that the target definition should be created in the parent project of your product project.

Create a target definition by highlighting your father project->Right click-> new-> Other-> Target Definition.  During creation select "Use workspace configuration."  The path to your downloaded plugin was added to this Location.
After the Target is created, Navigate to the content tab and select Manage Using: Features

This reduces the number of possible dependencies to only the ones needed to run.

You should now see the dependency checked in the list.

Creating the target resolved the other twenty or so dependency errors but the one under the title still throws an error.

I've learned that the product file is the file that calls the third party plugin in runtime.

The RCP app launches, but I cannot import the third party plugin in the bound classes created using this tutorial, to be used to obtain objects programmatically.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html

I have a shell of a program running and just need to implement the classes for each window with the objects I can get from a third party plugin import.

Thanks,

**(Solution)**

Thanks Brian for resetting my thinking which led me to learn about Eclipse a little more to figure this out.

The main problem is an external .jar is identified as the missing Import-Package.  Mine was org.apache.commons.beanutils.  You must go to the parent website and download the library.  In this case apache's website.  There is probably a better way to do this by repo.  I'm hoping I can export the product with all the required dependencies :p

I may be able to skip a step or two here, but these were my working steps.

1. Get .jar into Eclipse parent project.  Right click the parent and select New->Folder->Name it Lib->Finish.  Right click Lib->Import->File System->Navigate to .jar.  Highlight the included .jars->Right Click->Build Path->Add to the Build Path.
2. Add the missing .jar to your Ant class path.  Ant is used to build PDE apps using OSGi.  See the Eclipse Help for an explanation.  This will allow your missing jar to become visable in the feature project included-plugins tab.
   Window->Preferences->Ant->Runtime->ClassPath Tab->Add jar->Navigate to missing jar
3. Create a target definition as described above in your parent project and add your missing .jar to the target and set your target active.
   If target exists, In Locations widget window->Click Add->Directory->Navigate to missing .jar.->Next->  Verify plugins are recognized in window->Finish.  Click Set as Target Platform in upper right corner.
4. Open feature.xml in your feature child project. ->Click Add->Navigate to your added plugin->Click Ok
5. Save All - Launch product

Now onto the next dependency!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're confusing an Eclipse plugin with a jar dependency for your project. it sounds like your project needs a jar (the beanutils jar from Apache) . Depending on if your project uses Maven or ant (or something else) the way to add it to your project varies. Try googling something like "adding a jar in eclipse for a X build" where X is the tool used for your build (ant, maven, etc). No matter what you use, the end goal will be for that jar to show up the java Build path->Libraries for your project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that u need a better understanding of how dependencies are managed in OSGI/eclipse, therefore i concur with BrianPipa.

beware: that subject is quite large and not easy to understand and is way too large to be explained here. but be not afraid, google is ur friend:

a few pointers on research topics:

- the relation ship of bundle/plugin and jars
- how is code contained in a plugin exported (aka make visible) to other plugins so they can use it AND what needs to be done so that the using plugin (ie. declare that usage-dependency)?
- how are feature related to plugins?
- how are products related to plugins and features?
- what is a target platform ?

  - and how do i define it and what does it need to include ?
  - how do i set it ?